# Need the report specification in the Embeddable Reporting service to dynamically point to a different table name

Tags: sql, reporting, ibm-cloud

I am using the Embeddable Reporting service for Bluemix. I want to dynamically change the SQL text in the SQLQuery of a report definition so that the report is generated from a referenced table. The report specification can be changed using the https://erservice-impl.ng.bluemix.net:443/ers/v1/definitions//specificationAPI. However, how do you change the SQL text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps that are involved:

1. Author a report in the your favorite authoring tool against a sample table.
2. Grab the report specification by clicking **Tools > Copy Report to Clipboard**.
3. Locate the SQL string in the report specificiation and change it to a token that you can easily search/replace. For example: `Select * from %%DATATABLE%%`
4. Save this template in a file or in a string variable within your app.
5. Search/replace the string `%%DATATABLE%%` with the table that you want.
6. Execute the report:

   a. POST to `/ers/v1/packages/(package-id)/reports` with content-type `application/xml` and the specification as the body. The response will contain the location of the new report.

   b. GET `/ers/v1/reports/(report-id)/html` to render the report in HTML.

Here is an example in curl:

1. Connect to the service with your cloudant/Mongo URL and Embeddable Reporting Service credentials. For example:
   `curl --insecure -i -X POST --cookie-jar newcookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"bundleUri":"https:/(repository-uri)/"}' https://(ers-userid):(ers-password)@erservice-impl.ng.bluemix.net/ers/v1/connection`
2. Create a run instance from a specification against the packageId that contains your database.For example:
   `curl --insecure -i -X POST -b newcookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d '(report-spec-goes-here)' https://erservice-impl.ng.bluemix.net/ers/v1/packages/(package-id)/reports`

Here is an example response:

```
{   
   ...   
   "_links": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "href": "/ers/v1/reports/JwVd3JkeR3SFUkLlOi1bWw/html",
         "disposition": "paged",
         "mimeType": "text/html"
       },
       ... other formats ...
      ]   
     },   
     "_bundleID": "JwVd3JkeR3SFUkLlOi1bWw"
}
```

You can now run the response._links.formats.href

Run the instance in HTML. For example:
`curl --insecure -i -X GET -b newcookies.txt https://erservice-impl.ng.bluemix.net:443/ers/v1/reports/JwVd3JkeR3SFUkLlOi1bWw/html`

Get the HTML back.